# How to convert a full ascii string to hex in python?

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I have this string:
     `string = '{'id':'other_aud1_aud2','kW':15}'`

And, simply put, I would like my string to turn into an hex string like this:`'7b276964273a276f746865725f617564315f61756432272c276b57273a31357d'`

Have been trying `binascii.hexlify(string)`, but it keeps returning:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Also it's only to make it work with the following method:`bytearray.fromhex(data['string_hex']).decode()`

For the entire code here it is:

```
string_data = "{'id':'"+self.id+"','kW':"+str(value)+"}"
print(string_data)
string_data_hex = hexlify(string_data)
get_json = bytearray.fromhex(data['string_hex']).decode()
```

Also this is python 3.6

Comment: I was able to run same piece of code by replacing intial and trailing `'` with `"`.

Comment: @mad_ 

string_data = "{'id':'"+self.id+"','kW':"+str(value)+"}"

print(string_data)

string_data_hex = hexlify(string_data)

Tried but still the same issue, by the way this is python 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `encode()`the string:

```
string = "{'id':'other_aud1_aud2','kW':15}"
h = hexlify(string.encode())
print(h.decode())
# 7b276964273a276f746865725f617564315f61756432272c276b57273a31357d

s = unhexlify(hex).decode()
print(s) 
# {'id':'other_aud1_aud2','kW':15}
```

Comment: Oh didn't see the encode, yes i think that worked, thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky bit here is that a Python 3 string is a sequence of Unicode characters, which is not the same as a sequence of ASCII characters.

- In Python2, the `str` type and the `bytes` type are synonyms, and there is a separate type, `unicode`, that represents a sequence of Unicode characters.  This makes it something of a mystery, if you have a string: is it a sequence of bytes, or is it a sequence of characters in some character-set?
- In Python3, `str` now means `unicode` and we use `bytes` for what used to be `str`.  Given a string—a sequence of Unicode characters—we use `encode` to convert it to some byte-sequence that can represent it, *if* there is such a sequence:

  ```
  >>> 'hello'.encode('ascii')
  b'hello'
  >>> 'sch\N{latin small letter o with diaeresis}n'
  'schön'
  >>> 'sch\N{latin small letter o with diaeresis}n'.encode('utf-8')
  b'sch\xc3\xb6n'
  ```

  but:

  ```
  >>> 'sch\N{latin small letter o with diaeresis}n'.encode('ascii')
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
  ```

Once you have the `bytes` object, you already know what to do.  In Python2, if you have a `str`, you have a `bytes` object; in Python3, use `.encode` with your chosen encoding.