# Python 3: Unable to convert ASCII String to Hexadecimal

Tags: python-3.x, hex, ascii

Python Version: 3.7.2
I need to convert a string in ASCII like `Øâþ   ÿþ  !Zk2ìm "Ï"À>q  úÞ` to Hexademical, which in this case would be `d8 e2 02 12 02 fe 01 20 9b 10 20 20 03 ff 07 fe 20 20 21 5a 6b 32 ec 17 6d 20 0e 22 cf 22 c0 3e 71 20 02 20 03 fa de`. I found several solutions for doing this on Python 2, however I can't find any way of doing this on Python 3.

To summarise: The intender behaviour is **ASCII to HEX** as follows:
`Øâþ   ÿþ  !Zk2ìm "Ï"À>q  úÞ` **TO** `d8 e2 02 12 02 fe 01 20 9b 10 20 20 03 ff 07 fe 20 20 21 5a 6b 32 ec 17 6d 20 0e 22 cf 22 c0 3e 71 20 02 20 03 fa de`.

I've even checked on https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html and found it works, but I'm unable to implement it in Python 3.

Comment: I think this might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620969/how-to-convert-a-full-ascii-string-to-hex-in-python][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the code:

```
print(*[hex(ord(letter))[2:] for letter in 'Øâþ   ÿþ  !Zk2ìm "Ï"À>q  úÞ'])
```

which gives the following output:

```
d8 e2 fe 20 10 20 20 ff fe 20 20 21 5a 6b 32 ec 6d 20 e 22 cf 22 c0 3e 71 20 20 fa de
```

`ord()` - get ascii code,
`hex()` - get hex from int,
`[2:]` - to omit `0x` in every number.

**EDIT**

Slightly modified version (to get `0e` instead of `e`):

```
string = 'Øâþ   ÿþ  !Zk2ìm "Ï"À>q  úÞ'
print(*['{:02x}'.format(ord(letter)) for letter in string])
```

Comment: Thanks Poolka, but in ```6d 20 e 22 cf``` subsegment, you got a lone `e` character in 1 byte, that's the problem that I was facing when I tried to omit the starting 2 characters from each byte. `e` is a single hex character which should take half a byte / 4 bits instead of the 8 bits it's taking currently

Comment: @HarshitJindal `e` is `0e` I guess. The leading zero is omitted by `hex()` function. Moreover `e` is pretty legal hex number. You may add leading zero if you need.

Comment: thank you so much. I can't tell how much I tried looking it up, but only found anwers for Python 2 or answers where the output had non-hex characters as well like ```>``` or ```!``` as in @Error - Syntactical Remorse's answer too. Could you explain why that solution led to non-hex characters in a hex output?

Comment: also could you please edit your answer such that it adds the extra ```0```'s where it's missing?

Comment: @HarshitJindal The answer by @Error - Syntactical Remorse is very similar. The difference is another representation - `bytearray` instead of plain string.

Comment: `bytes = [format(ord(char), '#04x')[2:] for char in s]1` If you don't want the leading 0s.

Comment: @Poolka just use the format I pasted above instead of appending a char mid string based on a ternary.

Comment: @HarshitJindal Added slighltly modified version. Followed advice by Error - Syntactical Remorse. Seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord()`:

```
s = 'Øâþ   ÿþ  !Zk2ìm "Ï"À>q  úÞ'
bytes = bytearray(ord(char) for char in s)
print(bytes)
```

**Output:**

```
bytearray(b'\xd8\xe2\xfe \x10  \xff\xfe  !Zk2\xecm \x0e"\xcf"\xc0>q  \xfa\xde')
```

That being said I can't match your output exactly because you copied and pasted a garbage char:

```
print(''.join(chr(char) for char in bytes)) # Øâþ   ÿþ  !Zk2ìm "Ï"À>q  úÞ
```

Comment: I was able to get this output but isn't this form called hex-ascii? I want my output to be plain hex, without any ascii characters in the data. Checkout the website link I added in the question. I want that type of output